# How to convert Data Object { "key.subkey": "value" } to { "key" : "subkey": { "value" } }

Tags: javascript, json, data-objects

I want to convert data object from:

```
let data = {
        "data.name" : "michael",
        "data.email" : "michael@xsx.com",
        "person.gender" : "male"
    }
```

into

```
{
    "data" : {
             "name": "michael",
             "email": "michael@xsx.com"
    },
    "person" : {
             "gender": "male"
    }
}
```

I tried a loop and trying to split key:

```
let newdata = new Object()
for (const property in datas) {
    let key = `${property.split(".")[0]}`
    let subkey = `${property.split(".")[1]}`
    newdata['key'] =  key;
    newdata['value'] = {subkey: `${datas[property]}`};
    console.log(newdata);
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
"data" : {
          "name" : {
                     "michael"
           }
 },
 "data" : {
           "email" : {
                     "michael@xsxx.com"
          }
 },
 "person" : {
            "gender" : {
                     "male"
            }
 }
```

What's next?

Comment: what you have tried so far ? please post the code

Comment: i have no idea im sorry, would you mind give me some clue? @CodeManiac

Comment: You can read about how to loop over properties of object, also read about `split` and then read about how to create an object and add properties and values dynamically.

Comment: thank you for give me insight i will try your suggest first @CodeManiac

Comment: hello i got some stuck what should i do next? mind for guide me @CodeManiac

Comment: read how to add properties to an object dynamically

Comment: That "result" has nothing to do with a valid JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the key/value pairs from your existing data, then use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to convert that into a new object with the split keys forming a nested object:

```js
const data = {
        "data.name" : "michael",
        "data.email" : "michael@xsx.com",
        "person.gender" : "male"
    }
    
const result = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  [key, subkey] = key.split('.')
  acc[key] = acc[key] || {}
  acc[key][subkey] = value
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```